# Can Electron App Work in a system without Chrome Browser Installed?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am new to electron and want to know if after building an application with it, i still need to install chrome browser.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can.

Electron is bundled with Chrome, so you don't need Chrome installed to run Electron apps. See [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/about):

> Electron accomplishes this by combining Chromium and Node.js into a single runtime

You can see the specific Chromium version that's used by an Electron version by looking at the [Releases page](https://electronjs.org/).

Comment: What about Node.js, do we need to install node to run electron apps? (Not to develop, just to run apps that are already packaged)

Answer (score 0):

Electron uses a chromium browser instance as its view layer. You don't necessarily need the full Chrome browser installed to run an Electron app, but chromium will need to be installed with the Electron app in order to run it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer sounds a bit misleading to me. The chromium needed by electron is bundled with it. It does not need a separate installation. By installing the electron app, you may not even realize that there is a chromium inside.